# Programmatically invoking active_record generator: how to pass the parent argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator

The parent argument is ignored, in all of these cases:

```
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, ["list_order:string", "name:string"], ["parent=Ecm::Toplist::Base"]])
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, ["list_order:string", "name:string"], ["--parent=Ecm::Toplist::Base"]])
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, ["list_order:string", "name:string"], "parent=Ecm::Toplist::Base"])
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, ["list_order:string", "name:string"], "--parent=Ecm::Toplist::Base"])
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: How about `Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, "list_order:string", "name:string", "--parent=Ecm::Toplist::Base"])`

Comment: It does not create the migration, when passoing the arguments like this :( But indeed, it sets the parent correctly. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Correct way will be

```
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, "list_order:string", "name:string"], { parent: "Ecm::Toplist::Base"})
```

But be careful, according to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb) once you specify :parent, the migration will not be invoked.

The correct way to generate model with migration will be

```
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model", [name, "list_order:string", "name:string"], {migration: true, timestamps: true})
```